# Swift;Casting custom viewcontroller to viewcontroller

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I have a struct that handles alerts for me. It just has one function:

```
func presentAlert(_ title:String, _ message:String, _ presenter:ViewController) {

        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        presenter.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

I can call this fine from the viewcontroller. But on a subclass, AddTopicViewController I am getting an error:

```
myController.alert.presentAlert("Form errors", strErrMsg, self)

//error from compiler
Cannot convert value of type 'AddTopicViewController' to expected argument type 'ViewController'
```

So, two questions:

Since AddTopicVC is a subclass of VC I thought it would pass through
    for something requiring a VC. Obviously wrong on that one. Could
    someone explain the flaw in my logic on that?

Any suggestions on how to accomplish my goal? The app has a lot of
    validation and alerts are presented whenever the user hasn't entered
    required data, but all the viewcontrollers are subclass. I tried
    extending viewcontroller with the function but the subclasses gave
    an error that the method wasn't available.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is defined `AddTopicViewController`? I'd tend to say/guess that's it's inherited from `UIViewController`, not `ViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, that was my error.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the presumed base class, `UIViewController`, which all view controllers inherit from.

```
func presentAlert(_ title:String, _ message:String, _ presenter:UIViewController)
```

Alternatively use an extension of `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentAlert(_ title:String, _ message:String) {

        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, I see where I fell off the rails. Thanks!